# How to handle try-catch blocks and null checks in dash callback functions and Pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am a beginner in Plotly Dash and Pandas. I have written callback function in Dash that filters  a dataset and creates visualizations.

1. For callbacks in Dash, is it necessary for me to explicitly give any try catch block, like I generally give for any normal function? Also, how does try-catch exception work in Dash?
2. Also, if I want to check if a variable x is null in Python I do -

```
if x is not None
```

But if kdf is a dataframe and I want to check if its null or not, how to check that?

3. can I return something as None from a dash callback? For example

```
if x is None:
   return None
```

I am sharing my code snippet below as an example. How should the code ideally look if I were to incorporate null checks and try-catches?

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='appearance-graph', component_property='figure'),
    Input('intermediate-value', 'data'),Input(component_id=geo_radiobutton, component_property='value')
)
def update_graph(filtereddata, selected_criteria):
    #kdf=delivery[delivery['batsman']==selected_batsman]
    kdf=pd.read_json(filtereddata,orient='split')
    if selected_criteria is None:
        return None
    if (selected_criteria=='Appearance'):
        kptable1 = kdf.pivot_table(index='bowling_team', columns='over', values='batsman', aggfunc='count',
                                   fill_value=0) / len(delivery) * 100
        line_fig = px.imshow(kptable1, text_auto=".3%", aspect="equal")
        return line_fig
    if (selected_criteria=='Runs'):
        kptable1 = kdf.pivot_table(index='bowling_team', columns='over', values='total_runs', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
        line_fig = px.imshow(kptable1,text_auto=True,zmax=20)
        return line_fig
```

Answer (score 0):

> For callbacks in Dash, is it necessary for me to explicitly give any try catch block, like I generally give for any normal function?

It depends if you want a specific behavior on `catch` or not. But just so you know, if your callback code fails and raises an error, the app will not crash. In debug mode, you'll see an error notification pop in the top right corner of the web interface.

> Also, how does try-catch exception work in Dash?

The question is a bit vague, but if you want to raise an error the *Dash way*, you can raise a [`PreventUpdate` error](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks).

> But if `kdf` is a dataframe and I want to check if its null or not, how to check that?

I believe what you mean here is to check that `kdf` is an empty dataframe right? In that case, you can use the [`empty`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) Dataframe property, with `if kdf.empty: ...`.

> can I return something as None from a dash callback?

This is close to the first questions. Instead of returning `None`, you can either `raise` a `PreventUpdate` error, or return the `dash.no_update` value. The ["Advanced Callbacks" documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks) will once again help you.

> How should the code ideally look if I were to incorporate null checks and try-catches?

Putting all the above points together, you could write something like:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output("appearance-graph", "figure"),
    Input("intermediate-value", "data"),
    Input(geo_radiobutton, "value"),
)
def update_graph(filtereddata, selected_criteria):
    if selected_criteria is None or filtereddata is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    kdf = pd.read_json(filtereddata, orient="split")

    if selected_criteria == "Appearance":
        kptable1 = (
            kdf.pivot_table(
                index="bowling_team",
                columns="over",
                values="batsman",
                aggfunc="count",
                fill_value=0,
            )
            / len(delivery)
            * 100
        )
        line_fig = px.imshow(kptable1, text_auto=".3%", aspect="equal")

    elif selected_criteria == "Runs":
        kptable1 = kdf.pivot_table(
            index="bowling_team",
            columns="over",
            values="total_runs",
            aggfunc="sum",
            fill_value=0,
        )
        line_fig = px.imshow(kptable1, text_auto=True, zmax=20)

    else:
        raise PreventUpdate

    return line_fig
```

*NB: I don't know what you wanted to do with the commented line* `#kdf=delivery[delivery['batsman']==selected_batsman]`

Comment: Ok I see that if any exception occurs at all the message is shown at the corner of the page and App does not crash. But when users use the App and any exception occurs, I want to show a message like - "Please reload page" or "Please close current browser & try again later" in alert box.  So how to handle that for a better user experience?

Comment: You have many different ways of implementing such a feature. A simple way is probably to define a [dcc.Store](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store) containing the `error` data (empty by default), and output a value in this store if an error occurs (otherwise use `no_update`). You can then define a second callback that takes as input this error store and deals with the alert box (a simple [alert("My error message")](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)) in JS can also do the trick.